# openal: Get the current playing position of a source

Tags: audio, streaming, core-audio, openal

How do you get the current position of a playing source in openal? I guess I mean, what position in the audio is currently playing on the hardware after its gone through your buffers, openal's buffers, the hardware buffers, etc.

I've had a brief look at the api but I'm not quite sure what AL_SAMPLE_OFFSET/AL_BYTE_OFFSET/AL_SEC_OFFSET are meant to represent.  If I am playing a streaming source, I don't seem to get a constantly increasing number, it seems maybe I'm getting a position in the current playing buffer? (or of all buffers?)

for example, while playing, I loop and run this code:

```
alGetSourcef( sources[0], AL_SAMPLE_OFFSET, &secoffset );
printf(" - %f samples\n", secoffset);
```

and get

```
 - 0.000000 samples
 - 8192.000000 samples
 - 9216.000000 samples
 - 5632.000000 samples
```

which doesn't seem to be increasing.

This is on macos 10.7 with latest xcode 4.3 but I'm assuming it should be similar on other platforms.

update:

I've tried increasing the buffer size and it does actually look like its only the current position in the currently playing buffer:

```
 - 0.000000 bytes
 - 18432.000000 bytes
 - 20480.000000 bytes
 - 36864.000000 bytes
 - 36864.000000 bytes
 - 55296.000000 bytes
 - 55296.000000 bytes
 - 73728.000000 bytes
refilling buffer 2408
re-queued buffer 2408
 - 16384.000000 bytes
 - 34816.000000 bytes
 - 34816.000000 bytes
 - 51200.000000 bytes
 - 51200.000000 bytes
 - 69632.000000 bytes
refilling buffer 2409
re-queued buffer 2409
```

So given that, is there a decent way of keeping track as openal plays through multiple different buffers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those offsets are from beginning of queued buffers. You need to manually count size of already unqueued buffers and add to this number.

Here, if you read the [documentation](http://connect.creativelabs.com/openal/Documentation/OpenAL%201.1%20Specification.pdf), it says on page 40:

> The position is relative to the beginning of all the queued buffers
>   for the source, and any queued buffers traversed by a set call will be
>   marked as processed.

Answer (score 0):

I know it pretty late, but if your are using `libsndfile` you can get position of current stream playback by just seeking file with mode `SEEK_CUR` and then converting samples to seconds. (of course if you are deviding buffer chunks by samples.) In my case my sample chunk is `8192` per buffer, and my buffers count that im streaming is `4`. If you are using byte offset instead of samples it becomes a little harder, since you need also convert byte offset to samples and then you need to multiple it by channels count aswell.

```cpp
float SamplesToSeconds(sf_count_t samples, int sampleRate) {
    float seconds = samples / (float) sampleRate;
    return seconds;
}

float GetCurrentPlayTime() {

    float sampleRate    = 48000; // You get the sample rate from SF_INFO.
    float bufferSampels = 8192;  // Samples per buffer that give nice chuck at 44.1HZ.
    float bufferCount   = 4;     // Count of streaming buffers.

    // Retrive the current read samples count.
    sf_count_t currentSamples = sf_seek(sndfile, 0, SF_SEEK_CUR);

    // Convert the current read samples to seconds.
    float position = SamplesToSeconds(currentSamples);

    // playSamplesOffset - is offset that needs to be subtracked from position, because 'currentSamples' is means current read 
    // samples not the play one. 
    // In general its to tricky. So when play started it reads first 4 buffers and returns its 'currentSamples' but this is
    // not actualy play postion, play position here is should be 0.01 or something like that, im not sure here but it work for my case.
    float playSamplesOffset = ((float) bufferSamples / sampleRate) * bufferCount;
    position = position - playSamplesOffset;

    return position;
}
```

Result in my case:
[image: Playback]